# pulsar spock groovy test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, apache-pulsar

How with groovy mock pulsar producer if I has code:

```
myProducer.newMessage().key(String.valueOf(1L)).value(nameBytes).send()
```

my producer is mock myProducer = Mock(Producer). But in the test I got NullPointerException

Comment: split this command to multiple to understand which `.` (dot) throws the null pointer exceptiom.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, should be:

```
TypedMessageBuilder messageBuilder = Mock()
myProducer.newMessage() >> messageBuilder
messageBuilder.key(*_) >> messageBuilder
messageBuilder.value(*_) >> messageBuilder
```